# You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/install.php on this server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I'm working on a migration right now and after completing all the necessary steps, I've come across this error when I try accessing the website.

```
You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/install.php on this server.
```

I did check my error log and this is what it comes up with:

```
sudo tail -10 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

The errors are as follows:

```
[Fri Mar 29 16:26:58.360971 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 41530] [client 66.102.6.237:43764] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/path_to_files/wp-admin/install.php
[Fri Mar 29 16:29:21.855448 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41505] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 29 16:29:22.220074 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41633] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 29 16:29:22.220165 2019] [core:notice] [pid 41633] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 29 16:29:57.546844 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41633] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 29 16:29:57.653695 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41707] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 29 16:29:57.653762 2019] [core:notice] [pid 41707] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 29 16:30:05.134525 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 41726] [client 130.63.49.63:52630] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/path_to_files/wp-admin/install.php
[Fri Mar 29 16:42:30.993688 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 41732] [client 130.63.49.63:52828] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/path_to_files/wp-admin/install.php
[Fri Mar 29 16:42:34.331212 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 41732] [client 130.63.49.63:52828] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/path_to_files/wp-admin/install.php
```

My .conf is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/path_to_files
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache2 Version: 2.4.29** (Ubuntu). My file permissions have been set to **755**.

Any help on how to resolve this would be great.

.htaccess code:

```
<files .htaccess>
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
</files>
<files readme.html>
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
</files>
<files readme.txt>
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
</files>
<files install.php>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
</files>
<files wp-config.php>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: Look for `.htaccess` file inside that path, seems it restricts access

Comment: I found the .htaccess, what exactly am I looking at? I've attached some code from that file, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to temporaly disable blocking access to php install files, after install is complete - enable blocking again. `Deny from all` blocks access for everyone. `Allow from your-ip` will enable access only for you. Place "Allow" before Deny on separate line.
This section:

```
<files install.php>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
</files>
<files wp-config.php>
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
</files>
```

Update: Instead of use order, allow, deny, there are a new option 'Require', so sections should looks like this:

```
<files install.php>
  Require host address
  # or Require ip ip.address
  # or Require local
</files>
```

[Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

Comment: so order allow,deny --> allow from all --> deny from all ? are those the 3 lines you want me to add in those files?

Comment: Yes, but better not to all, limit access to your computer.

Comment: Hey, so I got rid of the error but It's asking me to set up wordpress now instead it should just load the previous site on this new domain.

Comment: Wait a second, I`ll update answer. This directives are deprecated.

Comment: okayy for sure.

Comment: You should follow install procedure carefully to setup it on new domain